# Enabled VS Code Keyboard shortcut only when Extension is Enabled

Tags: visual-studio-code

I would like to make the "when" clause of a specific keyboard shortcut be only when a specific extension (the Python extension in my case) is enabled/active i.e. when I am busy working with a python project.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

There is [extension context for key bindings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_contexts) but I think it can only be used inside extension. Although in **keybindings.json** `extension` key is checked because adding it breaks the shortcut execution, it surely doesn't work like in example from the docs.

Try `"when": "extension == 'ms-python.python'"`

or `"when": "extension == 'ms-python.python' && extensionStatus == 'installed'"`

You could probably make simple extension of your own that would check ms-python.python status and provided you with a shortcut.

---

Best alternative is relying on document language, like rioV8 suggested:

```
   "when": "editorLangId == 'python'"
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this to the `when` clause of the key binding

```
editorLangId == 'python'
```